# file is too large to copy on 8 giga USB Mass Storage Device

Tags: boot, usb, usb-flash-drive

I am trying to copy a boot win 8 iso file (4.50 giga) on my USB Mass Storage Device with 8 giga free space and it says the file is too large? so is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep! This is possible, I've had the problem before. What you need to do is format the thumb drive to NTFS.

1. Right click on the thumb drive
2. Click "Format"
3. Choose NTFS

**edit: PLEASE NOTE THAT THIS WILL ERASE ALL DATA ON THE THUMB DRIVE**

Answer (score 7):

If your USB drive is FAT formated, the maxmimum Size for a **single file** is limited to 4GB. If you need to copy bigger files you have to format it in NTFS.